# How to show a view when a user clicks on pin annotation?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, mapping, mkpinannotationview

I am developing a project in which I have parse `json` data and save it into an array. From that array, I  have make a `UITableView` in which I have a number of businesses. With the help of their latitude and longitude, I show them on an `MKMapView`.

Now I want to add an event that is when I click on a pin annotation, I push a detail view over the pin of associated business. In same manner, when I click on row of `UITableView` and open the view relative to that row. So how do I do that with pin annotation of the business point?

For example, we have a list of places in a `UITableView` and a button ***add*** on navigation-bar which calls an `MKMapView`. When I click on the ***add*** button, I then display an `MKMapView`, and drop pins on map with their respective latitude and longitude.

Now when user clicks on pin number 3, I open the view of details of that pin. Similarly, when user click on row number 3, I open the same view as when he clicked on pin number 3.

How can I set that event in my project?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should look into the `canShowCallout:` method found [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKAnnotationView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/MKAnnotationView). There are also many online tutorials on how to do this. Hope that Helps!